# Split and transform a R character string into numerical vector

Tags: json, r, curl, rcurl

I want to convert the following json and put the values into a data frame.  It almost works but as.data.frame() puts everything into one row.

```
require(rjson)
require(RCurl)

y = getURI(url1)
y
[1] "[{\"close\":5.45836392962902,\"highest\":5.45837200714172,\"lowest\":5.45836392962902,\"open\":5.45837200714172,\"start_time\":\"2012-01-29T18:29:24-08:00\"},{\"close\":5.45837200714172,\"highest\":5.45837200714172,\"lowest\":5.45834791002201,\"open\":5.45835598753471,\"start_time\":\"2012-01-29T18:28:24-08:00\"}]"

x = fromJSON(y)
> str(x)
List of 2
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ close     : num 5.46
  ..$ highest   : num 5.46
  ..$ lowest    : num 5.46
  ..$ open      : num 5.46
  ..$ start_time: chr "2012-01-29T18:29:24-08:00"
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ close     : num 5.46
  ..$ highest   : num 5.46
  ..$ lowest    : num 5.46
  ..$ open      : num 5.46
  ..$ start_time: chr "2012-01-29T18:28:24-08:00"

as.data.frame(x)
     close  highest   lowest     open                start_time  close.1 highest.1 lowest.1   open.1              start_time.1
1 5.458364 5.458372 5.458364 5.458372 2012-01-29T18:29:24-08:00 5.458372  5.458372 5.458348 5.458356 2012-01-29T18:28:24-08:00
```

Instead of it being on one row.  I want them in two rows.

```
   close    highest   lowest     open                start_time  
1 5.458364  5.458372 5.458364 5.458372 2012-01-29T18:29:24-08:00 
2 5.458372  5.458372 5.458348 5.458356 2012-01-29T18:28:24-08:00
```

Is there something I can specify in as.data.table for this to work?

EDIT:

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(x,as.data.frame))
```

The above was able to coerce it into a data frame, but the time stamp column has two factors.  This next part has its own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059726/r-converting-json-time-format-into-posix)

```
y = do.call(rbind,lapply(x,as.data.frame))
str(x)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ close     : num  5.46 5.46
 $ highest   : num  5.47 5.46
 $ lowest    : num  5.46 5.46
 $ open      : num  5.46 5.46
 $ start_time: Factor w/ 2 levels "2012-01-29T21:48:24-05:00",..: 1 2
```

If I try to convert the POSIX format I get

```
 x$start_time = as.POSIXct(x$start_time)
 x$start_time
[1] "2012-01-29 CST" "2012-01-29 CST"
```

But it loses the time data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try:

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(x,as.data.frame))
```

Comment: The start_time column has 2 factors when I do this way.  Any idea how to get it in POSIX format?

Comment: @Kevin `as.POSIXct`? `as.POSIXlt`? Read up and take your pick.

Comment: I tried those.  The dates are correct but it seems to strip out the time.  When I use as.POSIXlt it gives me the wrong time.

Comment: @Kevin Those functions can't read minds. Your time format doesn't look recognizable to me. You'll have to tell `as.POSIXct` how your time is formatted to get it to read correctly. I suggest you reread `?asPOSIXct` carefully, paying particular attention to `strptime`.

Comment: It is in time string format for JSON http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521185%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Kevin That's great. Since you've solved your original problem, and time format conversion is a wholly separate question, perhaps you should ask how to do that in a separate question?